# Compound index on array and text field in nested object in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

If I have index on element in array and "normal" element, but if they are in nested object, the second part of the index does not seem to be used. 
Example of data:

```
db.col1.insert(
{rt:{
   a:"1", 
   b: [{c:"1"}, {d:"2"}]
}})
```

Index:

```
db.col1.ensureIndex({"rt.b.c":1, "rt.a":1})
```

Query:

```
db.col1.find({"rt.a":1, "rt.b.c":1}).explain()
  "winningPlan" : {
                  "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                  "inputStage" : {
                          "stage" : "FETCH",
                          "filter" : {
                                  "rt.a" : {
                                          "$eq" : 1
                                  }
                          },
                          "inputStage" : {
                                  "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                  "keyPattern" : {
                                          "rt.b.c" : 1,
                                          "rt.a" : 1
                                  },
                                  "indexName" : "rt.b.c_1_rt.a_1",
                                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                                  "direction" : "forward",
                                  "indexBounds" : {
                                          "rt.b.c" : [
                                                  "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                          ],
                                          "rt.a" : [
                                                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                          ]
                                  }
                          }
                  }
```

So rt.a part of the index does not seem to be used, and I don't see why. If I do the same with root elements, both part of the indexes are used:

```
> db.col1.insert({a:"1", b: [{c:"1"}, {d:"2"}]})
> db.col1.ensureIndex({"b.c":1, "a":1})
> db.col1.find({"a":1, "b.c":1}).explain()
 {
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                    "b.c" : 1,
                                    "a" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "b.c_1_a_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                    "b.c" : [
                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                    ],
                                    "a" : [
                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
```

I am aware that you can use $elemMatch if two objects are in the same array, but in my example they are not and should not be effected by that MongoDB behavior.

Comment: What version of MongoDB is this? 3.0? I also reproduce this in 2.6.

Comment: Yes. 3.0. And yes I too have same problem in 2.6. The array seems to be the problem, but I still don't understand what is the root cause.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue happens because `rt` could potentially be an array? I'd search for a related issue in the MongoDB SERVER JIRA. If you can't find one you can open a ticket and get an explanation. I'm not seeing why index bounds need to be chosen so seemingly poorly here, but I'm also pretty sure this can't be the first time somebody has run into this.